# Efficiently creating a tensor of diagonal matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Assume a map from scalars to matrices of a fixed dimension.
How would one efficiently create a vectorized version of this map?

More specifically assume there is a constant vector lamb with n entries. 
Given a scalar t I'm interested in the diagonal matrix given by

```
np.diag(np.exp(lamb*t))
```

using numpy.
This will be an n times n matrix.
Now given a matrix T of size m_1 times m_2 I would like to calculate the tensor D of shape (m_1,m_2,n,n) given for 0 <= i < m_1, 0 <= j < m_2 by

```
D[i,j,:,:] = np.diag(np.exp(lamb*T[i,j]))
```

How would one efficiently get this tensor?

Comment: Could you add minimal representative sample data? What does `t` look like?

Comment: There aren't any restrictions for the scalar t and for the matrix T as well. Or what to you mean by "minimal representative sample"?

Comment: Well first off `lambda*t` doesn't seem like a valid syntax with `t` as scalar. Secondly, with minimal representative sample, I meant some sample data for `t`and a valid code (loopy code even) that could work on it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The word lambda is reserved in python. Locally I called the variable lamb instead of lambda which is of type ndarray. Thus multiplication by a scalar is defined as entrywise multiplication with t. The answer given by Paul Panzer produces the output I'm interested in.

Comment: We are lazy.  We don't like to make up test cases.  And we don't like the potential ambiguity of word problems.  Good answers include working examples.  Good questions should as well.

Answer (score 2):

One comparatively straight-forward way would be using `einsum`.

Example:

```
>>> T = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,6,7]])
>>> lam = np.array([1,2,5])
>>> D = np.zeros((*T.shape, n, n))
>>> np.einsum('ijkk->ijk', D)[...] = np.exp(np.multiply.outer(T, lam))
>>> D
array([[[[2.71828183e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 7.38905610e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.48413159e+02]],

        [[7.38905610e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 5.45981500e+01, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.20264658e+04]],

        [[2.00855369e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 4.03428793e+02, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.26901737e+06]]],


       [[[5.45981500e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 2.98095799e+03, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 4.85165195e+08]],

        [[4.03428793e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 1.62754791e+05, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.06864746e+13]],

        [[1.09663316e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 1.20260428e+06, 0.00000000e+00],
         [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.58601345e+15]]]])
```

You can speed this up a little bit using the `out` keyword to avoid one copy:

```
np.exp(np.multiply.outer(T, lam), out=np.einsum('ijkk->ijk', D))
```

Comment: Thank you! Something like this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I cannot apply `np.multiply.outer`, it has to be changed to `np.multiply.fun.outer`.